# Multithreading for StreamLit and Kite.connect()

Tags: multithreading, streamlit

I am trying to build my own charting platform. I am getting the live stocks data from Zerodha using the API and trying to chart it with the help of streamlit. Till now i was using Dash and things were working great but now i want to shift to streamlit because of the feature streamlit is providing.
I tried

```
import streamlit as st
from threading import Thread
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx

def target():
    kite.connect(threaded=True)

t = Thread(target=target)
add_script_run_ctx(t)

fig = plotly_plot(signalsdf)
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

I'm getting this error

```
2023-06-14 14:51:15.581 Thread 'Thread-3 (run)': missing ScriptRunContext
2023-06-14 14:51:15.581 Thread 'Thread-3 (run)': missing ScriptRunContext
```

Or should i try pool executor ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The add_script_run_tx function accepts thread and the streamlit context as input. So first you need to get the context, and pass it to the add_script_run_tx function.

Code example:

```
import streamlit as st
from threading import Thread
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx, get_script_run_ctx

def target():
    kite.connect(threaded=True)

t = Thread(target=target)
ctx = get_script_run_ctx()
add_script_run_ctx(thread=t, ctx=ctx)

fig = plotly_plot(signalsdf)
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Andrew saved my day, I created a decorator that runs a long running function in thread. Here is my code, if anyone find it useful

```py
## function wrapper
def run_in_thread(func):
    from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx, get_script_run_ctx
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        ctx = get_script_run_ctx()
        add_script_run_ctx(thread, ctx)
        thread.start()
    return wrapper

# define the function
@run_in_thread
def func():
    <long running code>
    st.session_state.xxx = yyy
    st.toast('finished')

# in main code:
func()
```